# Query to Get Counts of Ids under 2 different Conditions with Case When Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case-when

So I Have a Table Structure like the one below.

[image: Sample Current DB View]

Here are the Conditions:

1. I call 'Tag' as the IDs with none of Condition(x) as NULL.
2. I call 'UnTag' as the IDs with any of the Condition(x) is NULL.
3. I want to Classify 'Classification1' in the below Format:

[image: New Classification Using CASE WHEN Statement]

I want the output in the following structure:

[image: Final Output]

I wrote a code but somehow it is not giving me the desired result.
I Used Case when to Classify the Classification1 and then ran a sub-query for taking out Count. 
Please help if there is a different Approach and how to incorporate the Case when in Group by statement.

I wrote this query:
`SELECT
CASE 
WHEN UPPER(CM1.Classification1) IN ('A', 'C','G') THEN 'X'
WHEN UPPER(CM1.Classification1) IN ('B', 'F') THEN 'Y'
WHEN UPPER(CM1.Classification1) IN ('D', 'E') THEN 'Z'
ELSE 'Undefined' END AS New_Classification,
(SELECT 
COUNT(CASE 
WHEN UPPER(CM2.Classification1) IN ('A', 'C','G') THEN 'X'
WHEN UPPER(CM2.Classification1) IN ('B', 'F') THEN 'Y'
WHEN UPPER(CM2.Classification1) IN ('D', 'E') THEN 'Z'
ELSE 'Undefined' END) 
FROM TABLE1 CM2 WHERE 
CM2.Condition1 IS NOT NULL AND
CM2.Condition2 IS NOT NULL AND
CM2.Condition3 IS NOT NULL AND
CM2.Condition4 IS NOT NULL AND
CM1.ID=CM2.ID) AS Count_of_tagged,
(SELECT 
COUNT(CASE
WHEN UPPER(CM3.Classification1) IN ('A', 'C','G') THEN 'X'
WHEN UPPER(CM3.Classification1) IN ('B', 'F') THEN 'Y'
WHEN UPPER(CM3.Classification1) IN ('D', 'E') THEN 'Z'
ELSE 'Undefined' END) 
FROM TABLE1 CM3 WHERE 
(CM3.Condition1 IS NULL OR
CM3.Condition2 IS NULL OR
CM3.Condition3 IS NULL OR
CM3.Condition4 IS NULL) AND
CM1.ID=CM2.ID) AS Count_of_untagged
FROM TABLE1 CM1`

Comment: Please show us your query, so we can help you figure out why it's not giving the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a subquery, as a starting point I came up with:

```
    SELECT CASE Classification1
             WHEN 'A' THEN 'X'
             WHEN 'B' THEN 'Y'
             WHEN 'C' THEN 'X'
             WHEN 'D' THEN 'Z'
             WHEN 'E' THEN 'Z'
             WHEN 'F' THEN 'Y'
             WHEN 'G' THEN 'X'
           END new_classification,
           SUM(
             Condition1 IS NOT NULL AND
             Condition2 IS NOT NULL AND
             Condition3 IS NOT NULL AND
             Condition4 IS NOT NULL  /* 1 for true, 0 for false */          
           ) tagged_count,
           SUM(
             Condition1 IS NULL OR
             Condition2 IS NULL OR
             Condition3 IS NULL OR
             Condition4 IS NULL            
           ) untagged_count,
      FROM table_name
  GROUP BY new_classification
```

Answer (score 0):

Can give a try at the following sql and tell me if this is what you need

```
select 
CASE 
      WHEN classification ='A'  THEN 'X'
      WHEN classification ='B'  THEN 'Y'
      WHEN classification ='C'  THEN 'X'
      WHEN classification ='D'  THEN 'Z'
      WHEN classification ='E'  THEN 'Z'
      WHEN classification ='F'  THEN 'Y'
      WHEN classification ='G'  THEN 'X'
END as classification, 
sum(case when condition1 is not null and condition2 is not null and condition3 is not null and condition4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as tagged
sum(case when condition1 is null or condition2 is null or condition3 is null or  condition4 is null then 1 else 0 end) as untagged
 from table
GROUP   BY CASE 
      WHEN classification ='A'  THEN 'X'
      WHEN classification ='B'  THEN 'Y'
      WHEN classification ='C'  THEN 'X'
      WHEN classification ='D'  THEN 'Z'
      WHEN classification ='E'  THEN 'Z'
      WHEN classification ='F'  THEN 'Y'
      WHEN classification ='G'  THEN 'X'
END ;
```